# How to maintain different maven environments for production and development?

Tags: java, maven, build, ivy, artifactory

In a Java world where people use Maven/Ivy to manage dependencies, how should one maintain multiple environments/repositories (artifactory) for production and development environments?

The developers need to have a local repository for development (and sharing prototype libraries) where as a few of the jars need to be available in the Production repository. Some of the projects should build seamlessly in development environment and production.

This can be achieved by maintaining separate repository URL's in different environment, but what is the best way to do it , with minimal changes in configurations (pom.xml).

What can be the approaches to automate this?

Update : 
Also a good feature to have would be least config (e.g pom.xml) required to start a new project. But it is ok set up the development machine once with a settings file (e.g $M2_HOME/settings.xml)

Answer (score 5):

You may want to consider profiles. They support repository override.
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Seems useful : by as you see in the update to the question, this approach would require a lot of settings while starting a project - defining a pom with all the environment specific repository settings..

Comment: As far as I remember, you only can override in profile parts that you need. So just repository definition will be sufficient.

Comment: Profiles is the most flexible solution. Only alternative is a different settings file on development and production